# Break up a base64 image into an array of pixels using PHP

Tags: php, base64

I have some PHP to convert an image into Base64:

```
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$image = base64_encode($data);
```

This gives me a long, random looking string. How do I break this image up into and array of individual pixels using PHP?

How exactly are pixels separated in a base64 string? Is it different for different image types (JPG, PNG, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a short answer, you cannot. Not with `base64_encode` for sure.

`base64_encode` encodes the jpg or png data into, well base64.
This means that it uses 64 different characters to encode bits into letters, which has (almost) nothing to do with what you want to achieve, since the raw data is actually compressed according to the file format.
(If you are interested in learning more about base 64 encoding, I would suggest [this quite short video](https://youtu.be/aUdKd0IFl34))

What you want to do is get the color value of each pixel one by one.
So for starters you should use the [`imagecolorat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)  and loop through the width and the height of your image.

So your code would look something like this:

```
$imagename="image.png";

$imgsize = getimagesize($imagename); //this return an array of info
$imgwidth = $imgsize[0]; //index 0 is the width
$imgheight = $imgsize[1]; //index 1 is the height

$im = imagecreatefrompng($imagename); 
//note that this is a function for png images
//use imagecreatefromjpeg() for jpg

$pixels = [];

for ($x = 1; $x <= $imgwidth; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $imgheight; $y++) {
        $pixels[$x][$y] = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
    }
}
```

This will store all your pixels rgb into the `$pixels` array.

To get a human readable version you should use `imagecolorsforindex` like so:

```
$color = imagecolorsforindex($im, $pixel[1][5]);
```

which will return an array of the three colors plus alpha